# O que é upcasting e downcasting na linguagem Java?

Tags: java, terminologia, conversão-de-tipo, cast

O que seria *downcasting* e *upcasting* em Java? Exemplos por favor.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 23):

***Upcasting*** é fazer um objeto se passar por um objeto que seja um supertipo dele. Ele sempre funcionará já que todo objeto é completamente compatível com um tipo do qual ele foi derivado. Como sempre pode ser realizado, é possível fazer implicitamente, ou seja, o compilador faz por você quando for necessário.

É muito comum ele ocorrer como parâmetro de um método que usará polimorfismo. O chamador manda como argumento um objeto que é o subtipo, o método recebe um parâmetro como se fosse o supertipo, mas funciona como um subtipo. Mas note que o polimorfismo é um mecanismo auxiliar e não ligado diretamente ao *casting*. É considerado uma coerção em tempo de compilação.

Algumas pessoas gostam de chamar de promoção de tipo.

***Downcasting*** é quando o objeto se passa como se fosse um subtipo dele. Não há garantias que funcione (pode lançar uma `ClassCastException`, o que obviamente é um erro de programação) e pode haver necessidade de conversões. O compilador só aceita se ele puder provar que o objeto se encaixará perfeitamente e seja de fato aquele objeto. Por isso deve ser explicitado pelo programador quando deseja essa ação. A coerção ocorre em tempo de execução.

Algumas pessoas gostam de chamar de demoção de tipo (apesar de ser um neologismo).

Existe um padrão normalmente usado para evitar a exceção quando não se tem certeza que dará certo:

```
obj instanceof Tipo ? (Tipo)obj : null
```

Nesse exemplo se o objeto não for do tipo adequado, ele criará um nulo e nem tentará o *cast*. Obviamente que qualquer tentativa de acesso ao objeto gerado será problemático, então é preciso verificar se o objeto é nulo antes de tentar acessá-lo, caso contrário, só trocará de erro.

Exemplos:

```
class Animal { 
    public void fazBarulho() {
        System.out.println("silêncio");
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal { 
    public void fazBarulho() {
        System.out.println("au au");
    }
}
class Cat extends Animal { 
    public void fazBarulho() {
        System.out.println("miau");
    }
}
class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();      
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Animal animal2 = new Dog();
        Animal animal3 = new Cat();
        dog.fazBarulho();
        animal.fazBarulho();
        animal2.fazBarulho(); //concretamente é um cachorro
        animal3.fazBarulho(); //concretamente é um gato
        System.out.println("-- Castings agora --");
        ((Animal)dog).fazBarulho(); //upcasting
        ((Dog)animal2).fazBarulho(); //downcasting, funciona
        ((Dog)animal3).fazBarulho(); //downcasting, dá erro porque um gato não é um cachorro
        ((Dog)animal).fazBarulho(); //downcasting, dá erro aqui
    }
}
```

Veja ["funcionando" no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UivujD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cqsmbtmd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Casting.java).

Quando não há garantias que o objeto terá tudo o que se espera daquele tipo, o *cast* falhará. É o caso óbvio de um gato tentando se passar por um cachorro. Quando o animal genérico tenta se passar por um cachorro também não dá. Embora coincidentemente nesse exemplo até poderia funcionar, o compilador não pode provar isto. O programador que está vendo todo o código sabe, mas nem sempre ele poderá ver todas as classes. E mais, é possível uma manutenção modificar a classe e o que funcionava deixar de funcionar. Então tem que ir pelo caminho seguro.

De uma maneira geral isto funciona igual em todas as linguagens que possuem herança.

Answer (score 11):

Para entender melhor estes conceitos você precisa primeiramente entender os conceitos de HERANÇA, de 'SER UM' e de POLIMORFISMO. Vamos lá...

**Herança**

Classes Gato e Leao herdam a classe Felino, logo Gato e Leao são felinos.

**'Ser um'**

Gato é um gato. Simples assim. rs

**Polimorfismo** (ser mais 'de um')

Gato, além de ser um gato, também é um Felino, logo Gato é polimórfico.

**UpCasting** (subir a hierarquia)

É quando uma superclasse recebe uma referência da subclasse. Implícito, pois gato É UM felino.

Ex:

```
Gato g = new Gato();
Felino f = g;
```

**DownCasting** (descer a hierarquia)

É quando uma subclasse recebe uma referência de uma superclasse. Não implícito, porque o compilador não sabe se realmente a instância é do tipo da subclasse declarada, pois, como neste exemplo, Felino pode ser um gato ou um Leao. Mas como o programador sabe que é do tipo gato, ele coloca a subclasse entre parênteses, indicando ao compilador que o Casting está correto.

Ex:

```
Felino f = new Gato();
Gato g = (Gato) f;
```

Obs.: se o casting não estiver correto, ocorre a excessão `ClassCastException`

Ex:

```
Felino f = new Leao();
Gato g = (Gato) f;
```

Comment: Valeu,Bruno! Ajudou mto!

Comment: Imagina, qualquer dúvida é só perguntar ;)