# Inicialização do wrapper Double com int não compila

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo, tipagem

Quero entender porque essa inicialização não funciona:

(1): `Double d = 10; // Não funciona`

Eu entendo que `Double` é um *wrapper*, o compilador deveria converter esta linha para:

(2): `Double d = Double.valueOf(10); // Funciona`

Mas parece que não é bem isso porque (1) não está compilando, se eu fizer (2) explicitamente compila.

Qual a justificativa para isso?

Comment: [Esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9102330/5524514) responde de forma direta e resumida o que ocorreu ai.

Comment: @DiegoF ali ocorreu algo um pouco diferente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com os comentário fica claro que há uma confusão entre [*boxing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Boxing) e [*casting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion). São conceitos completamente diferentes.

## *Boxing*

O que o tipo `Double` faz é o *boxing* de valores de ponto flutuante com precisão dupla. Ele não converte, não promove nada. Ele pega esse valor e coloca dentro de uma classe chamada `Double`.

Essa classe é um tipo por referência, portanto a variável que conterá o valor possui um ponteiro para o objeto onde estão os dados. O valor armazenado fica lá no objeto e só pode ser acessado indiretamente através do ponteiro. O compilador já faz isso pelo programador.

Isso é o que se chama encaixotar um valor em um objeto. Não tem nada de conversão aqui.

## *Casting*

*Casting* é um processo de promoção de um tipo para outro. Em alguns casos é só indicar para o compilador que o valor deve ser interpretado como se fosse outro. Em outro é precisa fazer uma conversão, já que sua estrutura interna é diferente. Quando é possível fazer de forma segura o compilador aplica o *casting* automaticamente em algumas situações preestabelecidas pela linguagem.

Falei disso em [O que é upcasting e downcasting na linguagem Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131091/101).

Isso acontece porque existem regras na linguagem de autopromoção de tipos compatíveis **apenas** entre os tipos primitivos da linguagem<sup>*</sup>. Funciona:

```
double d1 = 10;
```

`double` é um tipo "primitivo". `Double` não é, isso já é sabido. Então no uso da classe não há promoção de um número inteiro para o `Double`. Não há regra que determine o que deve ser feito.

Poderiam ter definido na linguagem, mas não o fizeram e até faz sentido não o fazer na própria linguagem. Se tivessem feito, poderia ter um operador de *cast* implícito na classe `Double`. Isto, claro, se Java permitisse ter a definição de operadores nas classes.

É possível fazer um ***cast* explícito**, aí tudo ok:

```
Double d2 = (double)10;
```

É possível passar um valor que já seja um `double` através de literais:

```
Double d3 = 10.0;
Double d4 = 10d;
```

Ou através de um construtor ou outro método (usado na pergunta) que crie um número de dupla precisão:

```
Double d5 = new Double(10);
```

Note que o [construtor espera um `double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#Double-double-) e a promoção de inteiro para este tipo ocorre implicitamente conforme a especificação da linguagem.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LmCHX4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tcvcferd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Boxing.java).

O *boxing* para `Double` espera um número do tipo `double` para encaixotá-lo, se ele não recebe exatamente isto, não funciona.

Pelos comentários parece estar difícil entender isso, então vou repetir: Não tem regra que determine essa conversão automática, só funciona se for explícito.

Bastaria ter uma regras que determinasse que isso fosse feito pelo compilador que funcionaria. Os desenvolvedores da linguagem acharam que não era desejável, provavelmente porque acharam que poderia acontecer por acidente.

<sup>*</sup>Essa ideia de primitivo vai ficar complicada quando Java tiver dados básicos assim que não são primitivos (e terá em breve). E quero ver como eles vão lidar com *casting* já que eles decidiram não ter sobrecarga de operador, vão mudar de ideia ou será mais uma coisa capenga?

Comment: Entendo que existam regras de auto-promoção entre primitivos e entendo a diferença entre primitivo e wrapper. Sei que quando usamos um literal para inicializar um wrapper ocorre um autobox. Pela definição de autobox, o compilador substitui um valor literal por nomeDoWrapperDoPrimitivo.valueOf(literal), como mostrei no exemplo. A minha duvida é neste ponto. Fazendo explicitamente, ele compila porque valueOf tem sobrecarga para double, sei que o valor inteiro sofre autopromoção para double automaticamente. Não entendo porquê isso não esta funcionando implicitamente.

Comment: O que não está está funcionando implicitamente?

Comment: Double d = 10; //implicito, não funciona, Double d = Double.valueOf(10); // explicito, funciona, o compilador usa o conceito de autobox aqui de acordo com a documentação.

Comment: Está explicado na resposta porque não pode fazer.

Comment: A documentação diz que ao usar uma primitiva para definir um valor de um wrapper ocorre um autobox. De acordo com o autobox, o compilador chega na linha Double d = 10;  e faz a troca para Double d = Double.valueOf(10);, por isso é possivel trabalhar com primitivos e wrappers. A questão é que para o caso que coloquei isso não funciona. Você abordou outras alternativas, eu concordo. A questão é AUTOBOX.

Comment: Que documentação? *Autobox* é uma coisa, *autocast* é outra. Nos exemplos da pergunta está fazendo * autobox* ou *autocast*, no exemplo da pergunta nem tenta fazer *autobox* porque antes precisaria fazer um *cast*, que não foi feito. E a resposta deixa claro que não faz automaticamente.

Comment: Exato. Autoboxing só funciona com primitivos 'correspondentes'

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido este termo: "autopromoção"

Comment: @BrunoSilva como traduziria *type autocasting*?

Comment: @bigown No caso abaixo eu conheço como ampliação

"Isto acontece porque existem regras na linguagem de autopromoção de tipos compatíveis apenas entre os tipos primitivos da linguagem. Funciona:
double d1 = 10;"

Comment: @BrunoSilva e como você traduziria ampliação para o inglês? O termo não parece implicar que seja automático. Ampliação pode até ser sinônimo de promoção. Em inglês eu vejo muito o "promote*, *Amplificate* ou algo parecido eu nunca vi. Enfim, pode ser só um caso *lost in translation*, ... ou não :)

Comment: É rs. Tenho pouca experiência no ramo, apenas foi assim que aprendi, mas que seja... rs

Answer (score 1):

Considerando tudo que já foi explicado, a resposta é esta: **Não há ampliação para wrapper**, não é possível realizar ampliação e boxing ao mesmo tempo. Por isso primeiro é preciso realizar o cast para que o autoboxing funcione.

```
Double dWrap = (double) 10; // primeiro cast, depois autoboxing

double dPrim = 1; // Ampliação - ocorre apenas entre primitivos
```

*double* é maior que *int*, por isso do termo 'ampliação'.

[image: Tamanho dos Tipos]