# Por que o unboxing só pode ser feito para o tipo que foi realizado o boxing anteriormente?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, tipagem

Fui pesquisar o porquê de existir *unboxing* e *boxing*, as respostas que encontrei diz que existe para *value types* terem o mesmo comportamento de *reference types*, por exemplo nas listas não-genéricas `ArrayList`. Então está correto dizer que o *unboxing*/`Int32` faz o *casting* implícito da classe `System.ValueType` para `System.Object`? Ou seja, da estrutura `Int32` para a classe `Object`?

Então, por `Int32` ser uma estrutura e elas não suportarem herança, é por isso que o unboxing só pode ser feito para o mesmo tipo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Então está correto dizer que o unboxing/`Int32` faz o *casting* implícito da classe `System.ValueType` para `System.Object`?

[`ValueType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=net-8.0) é uma **classe** abstrata utilizada para dar a infraestrutura necessária para as estruturas, mas não é usada diretamente, então isso está incorreto.

> Ou seja, da estrutura `Int32` para a classe `Object`?

Isso está correto, dependendo do entendimento. O *boxing* é justamente pegar um [objeto por valor e encaixotá-lo em um tipo por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101), então no momento que é feito um *boxing*, implícito ou explícito, o que está fazendo é criar um objeto por referência, no caso um `Object`, e colocando como valor dele a estrutura original, ou seja, copia-se a estrutura para o objeto criado e uma referência é criada para este objeto.

> Então, por `Int32` ser uma estrutura e elas não suportarem herança, é por isso que o *unboxing* só pode ser feito para o mesmo tipo?

Não sei se entendi isso, mas acho que não, *boxing* não existe por causa de herança, existe por causa do local e semântica de armazenagem do valor.

O *unboxing* é copiar o valor de um objeto por referência para um tipo por valor, e o tipo desta estrutura deve ser compatível para receber o que estava armazenado no objeto.

Esqueça `ArrayList`, é obsoleto. Se está lendo material que fala disto ele está obsoleto também, procure coisa mais atual. Hoje em C# muito pouco *boxing* é necessário, embora alguns ocorram sem que a pessoa perceba porque raramente os programadores entendem o conceito por completo. Se estiver usando uma fonte ruim vai aprender tudo errado.

Tem uma pergunta aqui no site que fala sobre o assunto. Há um [confusão sobre a semântica do *boxing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55147/101).

Já falamos do [*boxing* do Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131136/101) que é muito parecido. Inclusive usando o [tipo `Boolean` como exemplo que é um tipo encaixotado do `boolean`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131136/101).

Provavelmente desejará saber [mais sobre `struct` e `class`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

Tem exemplo de [*boxing* em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/101). Note que hoje quase sempre os exemplos não têm relevância prática.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ops, quis dizer System.ValueType para Sytem.Object, erro meu