# Quando eu uso new em uma struct no C# estou alocando no stack ou no heap?

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem, struct, memória

Sempre entendi, até por ter visto isto primeiro no C++, que o `new` é usado para alocar memória no *heap*. Ao mesmo tempo que no C# dá para usar esse comando em `struct`s que sabemos que é um tipo por valor, e geralmente é alocado no *stack*. Se usar `new` a alocação ocorre no *heap*? E sem ele é no *stack*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O primeiro ponto é que há fortes diferenças entre C++ e C#, começando que `struct` em C# é muito mais específico que em C++. Toda tipagem dessas linguagens são diferentes. E o gerenciamento de memória também.

Outro ponto importante é que `struct`s e outros tipos por valor podem estar no *heap*, e qualquer linguagem é assim, porque um tipo por valor pode estar dentro de outro tipo por valor ou por referência. Os tipos por referência podem estar nos dois locais, mas no passado C# só podia estar no *heap*.

Até hoje, mas pode mudar, C# tem classes, que são tipos por referência, que só podem estar no *heap*.

Um tipo por valor pode estar no *heap* sempre que estiver dentro de uma classe.

Tipos por valor podem sofrer o chamado [*boxing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220870/101) e virar uma classe sem você perceber.

Ao contrário do C++, desafortunadamente, o `new` do C# não indica que está alocando memória no *heap*. Indica que alocará memória, mas pode ser em qualquer lugar. O que faz ele perder um pouco o sentido. Em C# ele existe mais para indicar que está usando um construtor e não uma função normal, já que a sintaxe de chamada do construtor e função normal, são idênticas, então serve para não deixar ambíguo para leitura.

Então, resumidamente falando, o `new` pode alocar na pilha. Ou alocar no *heap*, mas em forma de valor, ao contrário do `new` do C++ que sempre gera um ponteiro, então é um por referência.

Indo além, a especificação fala pouco sobre como ele deve proceder, então um compilador é livre para otimizar e fazer o que quiser, dentro de apenas algumas poucas restrições.

O contexto exato de onde e como o `new` é usado pode mudar muita coisa como o compilador e o .NET trata isso, não conte com algo fixo, definitivo e universal, consulte a [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Veja só ([coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/New.cs)):

```
using System;

public class Test {
    static Guid field;
    static void Main() {}
    static void MethodTakingGuid(Guid guid) {}

    static void ParameterisedCtorAssignToField() => field = new Guid("");

    static void ParameterisedCtorAssignToLocal() {
        Guid local = new Guid("");
        // Forçando o valor a ser usado
        local.ToString();
    }

    static void ParameterisedCtorCallMethod() => MethodTakingGuid(new Guid(""));

    static void ParameterlessCtorAssignToField() => field = new Guid();

    static void ParameterlessCtorAssignToLocal() {
        Guid local = new Guid();
        // Forçando o valor a ser usado
        local.ToString();
    }

    static void ParameterlessCtorCallMethod() => MethodTakingGuid(new Guid());
}
```

E como o [CIL é gerado no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;

[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[module: UnverifiableCode]
[module: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RefSafetyRules(11)]

public class Test
{
    private static Guid field;

    private static void Main()
    {
    }

    private static void MethodTakingGuid(Guid guid)
    {
    }

    private static void ParameterisedCtorAssignToField()
    {
        field = new Guid("");
    }

    private static void ParameterisedCtorAssignToLocal()
    {
        new Guid("").ToString();
    }

    private static void ParameterisedCtorCallMethod()
    {
        MethodTakingGuid(new Guid(""));
    }

    private static void ParameterlessCtorAssignToField()
    {
        field = default(Guid);
    }

    private static void ParameterlessCtorAssignToLocal()
    {
        default(Guid).ToString();
    }

    private static void ParameterlessCtorCallMethod()
    {
        MethodTakingGuid(default(Guid));
    }
}

namespace Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [Embedded]
    internal sealed class EmbeddedAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
}

namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Embedded]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Module, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    internal sealed class RefSafetyRulesAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public readonly int Version;

        public RefSafetyRulesAttribute(int P_0)
        {
            Version = P_0;
        }
    }
}
```

Código aproveitado da [resposta do Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204009/221800).

Answer (score 0):

> Se usar new a alocação ocorre no heap? E sem ele é no stack?

Em C#, é sempre necessário usar `new`, seja para classe, seja para struct.

`new` em classes alocam no heap, e `new` em structs alocam em no stack. Essa é a regra geral. No entanto, isso não vale para todos os casos.

`struct`s podem ser alocados no heap quando necessário, por exemplo, em situações onde o armazenamento do struct sobrevive ao stack frame onde ela foi criado.

No código abaixo, alguns gigabytes de `long`, que são `struct`, são alocados no heap, para serem preservados na coleção, até que o código morre por exaurir a memória RAM disponível (cuidado ao rodar esse código em computadores com swap ligado).

```
public static void Main (string [] args)
{
    var list = new List<long> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        list.Add (i);
}
```

Ou seja, `struct` podem ser ou acabar alocados no heap.

Por outro lado, é possível alocar objetos passados por referência no stack. Arrays são objetos passados por referência, assim como classes, e podem ser explicitamente alocados no stack. O código abaixo, o espaço de memória que suporta do `Span<T>` pode ter sido alocado no heap ou no stack.

```
int length = 1000;
Span<byte> buffer = length <= 1024 ? stackalloc byte[length] : new byte[length];
```

Além disso, classes normais poderão ser alocados no heap no futuro, como uma forma de otimização. A ideia é que objetos simples, que só são referenciados dentro de variáveis locais de métodos e que não "escapam", podem ser criados e destruídos no stack, nunca alocados no heap, já não são referenciados de nenhuma outra forma de fora do stack em questão.

Isso está em desenvolvimento, e pode ser acompanhados em nesse issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11192

---

Em resumo:

1. Sempre tem de usar `new`;
2. `new` as vezes aloca no heap, as vezes aloca no stack;
3. Classes são alocados no heap (pode mudar no futuro);
4. Structs são alocados no stack (mas podem acabar no heap).