# Por que adicionar uma variável, propriedade, método, etc. em uma string funciona?

Tags: c#, .net, string, concatenação-de-string

Quando eu adiciono uma variável, propriedade, método, enumerador, etc.. em uma *string*, ele funciona, mesmo eu não chamando o método `ToString()` por exemplo.

**Exemplo com tipo e inteiro:**

```
var example = typeof(bool);
var exampleInteger = 12;

Console.WriteLine("Resultado: " + example); // Resultado: System.Boolean
Console.WriteLine("Resultado: " + exampleInteger); // Resultado: 12
```

**Exemplo com enumerador:**

```
public enum Example {
    AnyField,
    Haha,
    Huehue,
    Popotao
}

public static void Main()
{
    var example = Example.Haha;

    Console.WriteLine("Resultado: " + example); // Resultado: Haha
    Console.WriteLine("Resultado: " + Example.Popotao); // Resultado: Popotao
}
```

- Por que isso acontece, o compilador realiza a conversão do tipo para **string** automaticamente? Como isso funciona?
- Porque o enumerador passa o nome do campo, ao invés do valor?
- Se eu não realizar a conversão manualmente (com um `.ToString()` por exemplo) pode ter alguma diferença de performance ou acarretar em um problema futuro?
- Em relação as boas práticas, qual seria a maneira correta de se fazer?

Comment: Não compreendi muito bem qual é a sua dúvida em relação a strings.

Comment: @gato É realmente como está na pergunta, queria saber porque isso ocorria, se o sistema fazia a conversão automaticamente, e se deixar pra ele fazê-lo poderia acarretar em perda de performance ou outros problemas. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Por que isso acontece, o compilador realiza a conversão do tipo para *string* automaticamente? Como isso funciona?

Como todos os tipos possuem uma representação textual, mesmo que não produza o resultado esperado o sistema de tipos gerenciado pelo compilador garante que o tipo seja automaticamente convertido para `string` sempre que ele for o mais adequado naquela posição. Isso é chamado coerção ou [*implicit casting*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131136/101).

> Por que o enumerador passa o nome do campo, ao invés do valor?

Porque escolheram assim, afinal o que interessa no enumerador é o seu nome e não seu valor. Poderiam ter usado o valor, mas fazia menos sentido. Isso é uma definição do [`Enum`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

> Se eu não realizar a conversão manualmente (com um `.ToString()` por exemplo) pode ter alguma diferença de performance ou acarretar em um problema futuro?

Geralmente há um pequeno ganho se fizer manualmente porque é comum o método que espera o valor ter uma assinatura com `string` e outra com `object`.

A primeira só é chamada se já receber uma `string` e opera diretamente no valor recebido, mas se não tiver essa assinatura obviamente não fará diferença porque só a outra forma poderá ser chamada.

A segunda será chamada se for outro tipo, a não ser que tenha uma assinatura com o tipo específico, o que é raro. A conversão será feita internamente. Pode parecer que o custo é o mesmo e só trocou de lugar onde se faz a conversão. O problema ocorre em [tipos por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) porque haverá um [*boxing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220870/101) ([mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55147/101)) e uma instância por referência será criada e o valor copiado para passar como `Object` Isto tem enorme custo de processamento e memória. Se o tipo já for por referência não há custo extra.

> Em relação às boas práticas, qual seria a maneira correta de se fazer?

A que for correta no contexto que for utilizar. Eu deixo o *framework* se virar porque na maioria dos casos a performance não é tão importante e o código mais limpo fica mais legível.

Comment: Quando você diz primeira seria `string` e segunda `object`?

Comment: @ViníciusLima isso mesmo.

Comment: Não entendi onde esta a ocorrer a conversão para `string`.

Comment: @gato Na pergunta por exemplo, eu concatenei uma `string` com um `int`. No final tudo não sai como uma `string` correto? O @Maniero respondeu: "o sistema de tipos gerenciado pelo compilador garante que o tipo seja automaticamente convertido para `string`".

Comment: @ViníciusLima esta a falar da concatenação não é `"Resultado: " + exampleInteger;`? Neste caso a conversão ocorre neste momento. É que deu a entender que você queria manipular as variáveis como uma `string`.