# Erro ClassCastException ao tentar fazer cast entre classes

Tags: java, exceção, herança, cast

Estou com o problema para realizar um "Cast" em uma classe, quando utilizo o método da classe herdada da o seguinte erro:

> "entidade.Aula cannot be cast to tableview.AulaTV"

Aqui dá a exceção descrita acima.

```
AulaTV atv = (AulaTV) new Aula().buscarPorCodigo("1ageoB2");
```

Segue as classes utilizadas:

```
public class Aula {

    private int id;
    private String codigo;
    private String titulo;
    private String conteudo;
    private Date dtCadastro;
    private String log;
    private int serie;
    private int disciplina;
    private int empresa;
    private int cliente;
    private File arq;

    public Aula() {
    }

    public Aula(int id, String codigo, String titulo, String conteudo, Date dtCadastro, String log, int serie, int disciplina, int empresa, int cliente, File arq) {
        this.id = id;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.conteudo = conteudo;
        this.dtCadastro = dtCadastro;
        this.log = log;
        this.serie = serie;
        this.disciplina = disciplina;
        this.empresa = empresa;
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.arq = arq;
    }

    // gets and sets

    public Aula buscaAulaPorCodigo(String codigo) throws Exception {
        Aula aula = null;
        try {
            aula = new AulaDAO().buscarPorCodigo(codigo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return aula;
    }

    public static Aula buscaNoListPorNome(List<Aula> list, String chave) {
        for (Aula a : list) {
            if (a.getCodigo().equalsIgnoreCase(chave)) {
                return a;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Classe AulaTV:

```
public class AulaTV extends Aula {

    private CheckBox checkBox;

    public AulaTV() {
        super();
        checkBox = new CheckBox();
    }

    public AulaTV(CheckBox checkBox, int id, String codigo, String titulo, String conteudo, Date dtCadastro, String log, int serie, int disciplina, int empresa, int cliente, File arq) {
        super(id, codigo, titulo, conteudo, dtCadastro, log, serie, disciplina, empresa, cliente, arq);
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
    }

    // gets and sets
}
```

Comment: Dá uma abreviada nesse código, esse monte de *get* e *set* são desnecessários pro entendimento do problema...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está tentando fazer cast da classe `Aula` como se fosse `AulaTV`, pois o método `buscaAulaPorCodigo` retorna um tipo `Aula`.

Você não pode converter um supertipo (no caso a classe `Aula`) em um subtipo (neste caso, `AulaTV`) por casting direto, o compilador não tem como garantir essa compatibilidade, por isso ele estoura a exceção. Você pode ler mais a respeito sobre *DownCasting*  e *UpCasting* [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/131092/28595).

Altere o retorno deste método, se espera retornar um tipo `AulaTV`, também garanta que o método `new AulaDAO().buscarPorCodigo(codigo);` irá retornar um objeto deste tipo.

```
   public AulaTV buscaAulaPorCodigo(String codigo) throws Exception {
        Aula aula = null;
        try {
            aula = new AulaDAO().buscarPorCodigo(codigo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return aula;
    }
```

E remova o cast da linha:

```
AulaTV atv = new Aula().buscarPorCodigo("1ageoB2");
```

Ou se não puder mudar a assinatura do método, outra maneira alternativa de se checar essa conversão é utilizando o `instanceof`, caso você tenha certeza de que o retorno será exatamente um tipo `AulaTV`, mesmo vindo assinalado como seu supertipo `Aula`, veja um exemplo (apenas para fins de demonstração, claro):

```
Aula aula = new Aula().buscarPorCodigo("1ageoB2");
AulaTV atv;

if (aula instanceof AulaTV) {
   atv = aula;
}
```

Comment: Nesse caso em todo o resto do código onde eu uso o método "buscaAulaPorCodigo(String codigo)" terei um erro, minha intenção de criar uma herança para isso é justamente poder reutilizar o métodos sem ter quer reescrever o método.

Comment: @LuisCalegari só que o cast que você está tentando fazer vai sempre da erro. Você não pode converter um supertipo em um subtipo, o compilador não tem como garantir essa compatibilidade, por isso ele estoura a exceção. Se não é possivel mudar a assinatura do método, então será necessário reavaliar a necessidade do cast.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda... ficou bem claro pra mim o conceito de *DownCasting* e *UpCasting* no post que vc indicou... Ainda não tinha conhecimento sobre esses termos...

Comment: @LuisCalegari uma sugestão, pelo que vi da implementação, você pode separar as duas classes, e criar uma interface comum entre elas, deste modo, será possivel chamar `Aula` onde se espera `AulaTv`.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade podemos ***sim*** fazer downcast. Se não fosse possível o cast não seria definido na linguagem. Só que no seu caso o ***objeto*** no qual você está aplicando o cast não é compatível com o tipo da variável na qual você quer armazenar.

Primeiro precisamos separar duas coisas, temos o tipo da variável que faz a referência e o tipo do objeto em si em memória. Eles podem ser diferentes. O tipo do objeto é definido pela classe que você usa para fazer o `new` e nesse caso foi a classe Aula. Isso significa por exemplo que ele não tem as estruturas da classe AulaTV e durante a execução a JVM consegue verificar que o objeto não tem um tipo compatível com a variável destino.

Isso fica mais claro de ver em situações onde temos uma hierarquia de classes em que a classe de mais alto nível é `abstract` porque aí você não pode fazer `new` nela. Um bom exemplo (porém apenas para entender a teoria, não é muito prático no sentido de problemas do dia a dia reais) é considerar uma hierarquia de classes para polígonos:

```
public abstract class Poligono { ... }

public class Triangulo extends Poligono { ... }

public class Retangulo extends Poligono { ... }
```

Você pode fazer coisas como as seguir:

```
Poligono p = new Triangulo();
Triangulo t = (Triangulo) p; //Isso é um downcast válido

Retangulo r = new Retangulo();
p = r; //Upcast não precisa de cast, o compilador aceita.
r = (Retangulo) p; //Novamente downcast

p = t; //Upcast não precisa de cast, o compilador aceita.
r = (Retangulo) p; //Novamente downcast, erro em tempo de execução
```

No seu caso como a superclasse é concreta você já tem um erro de cara porque o objeto é do tipo da superclasse diferente do exemplo que eu dei aqui.

Agora, a parte disso tudo, a ideia de uso de herança que você pensou não é a melhor forma de usar esse recurso da linguagem (embora algumas pessoas vão argumentar que não deveria nem ser usada nunca, mas isso é outra conversa). Ao que parece `AulaTV` é uma classe que cuida de aspectos relacionados com a tela, inclusive os métodos de busca da classe `Aula` poderiam (deveriam?) estar em uma terceira classe que cuidasse apenas dos aspectos relacionados ao acesso de dados, seja ele onde for, em um banco de dados ou outro repositório.