# Upcasting e Downcasting

Tags: java, classes, herança

Eu sei que *Upcasting* é converter um objeto da subclasse para a superclasse e *Downcasting* é converter um objeto da superclasse para a subclasse.

Mas em relação a perda de valores e esses afins, como fica?

Exemplo: Temos a superclasse `Carro` e a subclasse `CarroMelhorado`.

`CarroMelhorado` é um Carro, porém com coisas a mais. Porém se eu falar `Carro c1 = new CarroMelhorado();` a partir de agora esse c1 ganha novos atributos e métodos que podem ser usados ?

E em outro caso: `CarroMelhorado cm1 = new Carro()` aqui seria um *Downcasting*, só que cm1 do tipo `CarroMelhorado` possui coisas a mais que `Carro` não tem, mesmo `CarroMelhorado` sendo um `Carro`, com essa atribuição `cm1` perderia todas as suas coisa "a mais"?

Comment: Os exemplos dados nao se tratam de up e nem de downcasting. Recomendo a leitura do link a seguir para entender melhor os conceitos: [O que é upcasting e downcasting na linguagem Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131091/o-que-%C3%A9-upcasting-e-downcasting-na-linguagem-java?rq=1)

Comment: Só uma crítica construtiva: a palavra "perca" não é um substantivo.  O correto seria "perda".

Comment: Tudo bem, e qual seria uma aplicação real disso e com qual intuito ? Sou leigo no assunto, queria entender na prática e na teoria, no curso em que estou fazendo explica Upcasting e Downcasting superficialmente, visualizo melhor com exemplos reais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este caso que está dizendo que faz *downcasting* sequer compila portanto está fazendo nada, pelo menos nada válido. Algo mais geral não pode se tornar mais especializado justamente porque não tem tudo o que é necessário.

Eu não chamaria de *casting* algo que existe apenas na declaração da variável através de um construtor. O *casting*, implícito ou explícito, ocorreria se um objeto já existente fosse colocado em uma variável de outro tipo. Não havendo *casting* não pode se falar em perda.

*Castings* que envolvem perda não deveria ser permitidos implicitamente, e em alguns casos nem explicitamente. Em outras linguagens mais poderosas é possível estabelecer regras próprias de *casting* para cada objeto, mas não é o caso de Java.

A pergunta não é sobre *casting*.

Em parte isto está explicado em [O que é upcasting e downcasting na linguagem Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131091/101).

[O que você chama de atributo na verdade é um campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Comment: Até compila, mas tudo que a subclasse tiver de especifico deixa de ser visivel naquela objeto.

Comment: Me referi ao segundo exemplo, claro, o primeiro nem compila mesmo.

Comment: O segundo não compila: https://ideone.com/tdal5F, o primeiro é até bastante usual.

Comment: Realmente, fiz confusao com as classes citadas da pergunta.